# VB.NET: no warning when returning object that is not an instance of function's return type

Tags: vb.net

We have this:

```
Friend NotInheritable Class ConcreteGraphFactory
    Inherits AbstractGraphFactory

    Public Shared ReadOnly Instance As New ConcreteGraphFactory()

    Private Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Friend Overrides Function Create() As AbstractGraph
        Return New ConcreteGraph()
    End Function    

    Private NotInheritable Class ConcreteGraph
        Inherits AbstractGraph

        Private ReadOnly Question1 As New Question("Why isn't this showing a warning?")

        Public Overrides Function GetRoot() As IRoot
            Return Question1 '<---HERE
        End Function

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

And I have `IRoot`:

```
Friend Interface IRoot
    Inherits IQuestion
    Function GetContainer() As AbstractGraph
End Interface
```

And finally `Question`:

```
Public Class Question 
    Implements IQuestion

    ' code....

End Class
```

Why would VS not show a warning? `Question` does not implement `IRoot`...

Comment: Is there an inheritance chain between `IRoot` and either `Node`, `NonAnswer`, or `IQuestion`?

Comment: All classes implementing `IRoot` implement `IQuestion`, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the compiler to give an error there, then you need to set Option strict to On. You can do that on the Compile tab of the project's Properties. Or add `Option Strict On` to the top of the file that contains this code.

Here are a few pages that have more details about what Option Strict means.

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311329

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx

Option Strict Off means that the Visual Basic compiler doesn't enforce strict data typing. It will try to do implicit type conversions and throw run time errors if that can't be done.

I didn't think it had anything to do with `IRoot` being an interface, but after trying it out it looks like it does. If `GetRoot` returned a class that `Question` didn't inherit from, then you would get a compiler error even with Option Strict off.

Running with Option Strict off actually makes some things easier, especially when dealing with late bound COM objects. For the most part, you don't have to worry about type casts when writing code.

However, it's also one of the reasons many people don't like VB.NET. Personally, I liked it when I was working with it, but it's been long enough now that it does seem strange that the compiler wouldn't be doing all the strict type checking for you. I could always tell when some VB code had been generated via a conversion tool from C# because it would have a bunch of `DirectCast` calls that you wouldn't see in code that a VB developer had written.

When C# came out with the `dynamic` keyword in 2009, the VB.NET developers were thinking, "Meh. We've always been able to write code without worrying about types." Of course, VB.NET wasn't the same as `dynamic` in C#, but many of the early dynamic code examples were showing things that you could already do in VB with option strict turned off.

Comment: Why would having it off allow this to compile?  Is it because it's returning an interface, instead of a more implemented/complete type?

Comment: @Panzercrisis thanks for your question. At first I didn't think returning an interface made a difference, but it seems that it does. Good question! It's been too long since I've worked with VB.